Change WordPress Username maxmimum length
Would anyone please advice on how to set a hook to be applied to function.php
So that I can change the default WordPress Username Limit (40 Charachters).
Also I need to allow Arabic Charachters in Username to allow using Full name as Username
I found 2 plugin that might help, but they are not working properly and outdated:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-usernames-emails-characters/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-special-characters-in-usernames/
Please help
This is urgent
Thank you in advance

In WordPress 6.7, usernames are limited to 60 characters, and this value is hard-coded with no filter (source), so no proper way to change it.
Allowing more than 60 characters would mean changing core, which is bad practice.

I found the solution,
Thanks to this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-usernames-emails-characters/
But very important to select in options:
Solved the problem of not being able to register with certain languages

